# ¿Cómo seleccionar todas las filas en una consulta preparada?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta donde $selected_Inm varía dependiendo de un select

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM inm LEFT JOIN f_inm ON (inm.idInm=f_inm.Inm_idInm) WHERE idInm = :idInm AND F_idF = :idF ');
$statement->execute(array(':idInm' => $selected_Inm,':idF' => $selected_F));

while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
                    ****se ejecutan otras funciones
                 }
```

Este es el select

```
  <form action=""  accept-charset="utf-8" name="form_change_inm" id="form_change_inm">
    <select class="form-control" name="select_inm" id="select_inm" required  style="width: 200px;" onchange="change_inm();" >
      <option value="" disabled selected>Elige una opción</option>
      <option value="0">Todas las opciones</option>
      <?php foreach ($inm_array as $inm) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $inm['1']; ?>"><?php echo $inm['2']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </form>
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar todos los idInm cuando la opción del select sea "Todas las opciones" (cuando $selected_Inm == 0), es decir hacer la siguiente consulta sin tener que quitar "WHERE idInm = :idInm"

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM inm LEFT JOIN f_inmueble ON (inm.idInm=f_inm.Inm_idInm) WHERE F_idF = :idF);
$statement->execute(array(':idF' => $selected_F));

while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
                    ****se ejecutan otras funciones
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM inm LEFT JOIN f_inmueble ON (inm.idInm=f_inm.Inm_idInm) WHERE F_idF = ?';
$params = [$selected_F];
if (!empty($selected_Inb)) {
    $sql .= " AND specificColumn = ?";
    $params[] = $selected_Inb; 
}
$statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($params);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Cómo funciona  el ? y $params? Tendrás algún link para leer sobre eso?

Comment: En este caso $params es solo un array.  Tu tambien usas un array cuando llamas execute.  El simbolo ? se utiliza para no nombrar los parametros y tomarlos conforme el orden que los ingresas en el array.  Chequea el ejemplo 3 de el link que agrege.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion **NVL**:

Lo q hace es analizar el primer valor, y en el caso de q sea nulo lo remplaza con el segundo valor q le pases.

```
WHERE idInm = NVL(:idInm,idInm)
```

**Nota:** Solo usa el segundo valor cuando el primero q analiza es NULL. En tu caso podrias editar la opcion q retorna por defecto 0;

```
  <option value="">Todas las opciones</option>
```